# Need to find Max, Min, Avg number in Array - no size declared

Tags: c, arrays, undefined

So I have this array, I need to find the Min, Max, and Average. I have figured out how to get the Max, my code looks right for the minimum but it does not work so I must be missing something. I also need to find the average of the numbers entered. Everything I can find on this only works when you have the size of the array set. I have a max size set for the array but it does not get filled by user input. I have been staring and testing on this for days and still cant figure it out.

I know for the average I need something like (with added declartions at the top), but I cannot figure out how to get it to work:

```
for (i = 0; i < numOfGrades; i++) {
    sum += grades[i];
    }
avg = (double) sum / numOfGrades;
```

---

Here is the rest of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int grades [100]; 
int i = 0;
int small, big, input;

printf("Enter a series of grades. When done, enter any number above 100.\n\n");

while (i <= 100) { //while loop to set maximum for array
    printf("Enter grade:");

    if (scanf("%d", &input) == 1) {
        if (input >= 0 && input <=100) {  
            grades[i] = input; //if good, add to array
            i++;
            }
        else {
            printf("\n\nExiting entry.\n");
            printf("\n\nGrades entered:\n\n");
            i = i - 1;
            break; //exiting loop
            }
        }
    }
int x, y;
    for (x = 0; x <= i; x++) {
        printf("Grade: %d\n", grades[x]);  //print array
        }
    big = small = grades[0];
    for (y = 0; y < i; y++) {
        if (grades[y] > big) {
            big = grades[y];
            }
        else if (grades[y] < small) {
            small = grades[y];
            }
        }
    printf("Highest number : %d\n", big);
    printf("Smallest number: %d\n", small);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you *initialize* the array with some value (that let's say, can't be a valid grade), you'd be able to easily recognize when you reached the "end"...

Comment: Perhaps 1) `i <= 100` --> `i < 100`  2) Delete `i = i - 1;`.  3) `x <= i;` --> `x < i;`  4) Other things?

Comment: For your average code, `numOfGrades` is just the `i` from your `while` loop. Look at what `i` ends up set to: the number of grades input by the user. You just need to loop from 0 to that point to get the sum of the entered grades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you do the right thing:

```
 for (x = 0; x <= i; x++) {
```

Because `x <= i` will take you from 0 to the value of `i`. Then in your `min/max` loop you do this:

```
 for (y = 0; y < i; y++) {
```

So you are going from 0 to to `i-1`. You have 2 options:

1. Make the above loop correct with `y <= i`.
2. Dont decrement `i` in the `while` loop (Dont do this `i = i - 1;`) That way, `i` represents the number of numbers entered, instead of number of numbers entered -1 (you will need to fix the `x <= i` to `x < i`).

Here is a live example. http://ideone.com/ZEaDue

To calculate the average, you are doing the right thing, you can re-use `i` though:

```
int sum = 0, avg = 0;
for (y = 0; y < i; y++) {
    sum += grades[y];
}
avg = (double) sum / i;
printf("Avg: %d\n", avg);
```

Comment: This was amazingly helpful and work fantastic, except one minor detail, I needed to leave the `x  <= i` rather than `x < i`

Comment: @PhilipHudson, then use option 1.

Comment: I still had to get rid of the `i = i - 1`

Answer (score 1):

Actually you do have the number of grades

```
   if (scanf("%d", &input) == 1) {
        if (input >= 0 && input <=100) {  
            grades[i] = input; //if good, add to array
            i++;
            }
        else {
            numOfGrades=i;
            printf("\n\nExiting entry.\n");
            printf("\n\nGrades entered:\n\n");
            i = i - 1;
            break; //exiting loop
            }
```

As for the minimum, your logic should be like this:

```
for (y = 0; y < numOfEdges; y++) {
    if (grades[y] > big) {
        big = grades[y];
        }
    if (grades[y] < small) {
        small = grades[y];
        }
    }
```

The **else** statement I removed should do the trick. Also I would always use

`for(int var = 0; var < numOfEdges; var++)` in any of the loop constructs. It's easyer to follow the logic this way: You have counted the number of edges (numOfEdges), but your loop goes only to numOfEdges-1 since you start with index 0.